# Valores nulos de ajax para controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net

Estou recebendo valores `null` no objeto por parametro no `controller` do `asp.net core` via `ajax`

Segue o  `javascript` com o `ajax`

```
 var ClienteFornecedor = {
        Id: "0",
        Tipo: $('#selTipoAdicionar').val(),
        NomeRazaoSocial: $('#txtNomeRazaoSocialAdicionar').val(),
        NomeFantasia: $('#txtNomeFantasiaAdicionar').val(),
        CpfCnpj: $('#txtCpfCnpjAdicionar').val(),
        Endereco: $('#txtEnderecoAdicionar').val(),
        Bairro: $('#txtBairroAdicionar').val(),
        Cidade: $('#txtCidadeAdicionar').val(),
        Estado: $('#txtEstadoAdicionar').val(),
        Cep: $('#txtCEPAdicionar').val(),
        Telefone: $('#txtTelefoneAdicionar').val(),
        Celular: $('#txtCelularAdicionar').val(),
        Ie: $('#txtInscEstadualAdicionar').val(),
        Observacao: $('#txtObservacaoAdicionar').val()
    };

   var dto = JSON.stringify(ClienteFornecedor);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ClienteFornecedor/Adicionar',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data:  dto,
        success: function (result) {

            }

        }
    });
```

Verifiquei no debug e vi que está convertendo corretamento em `json`, porém o problema é que no `controller` da aplicação, o objeto está chegado com as propriedades `null`

Segue o meu controller:

```
    public JsonResult Adicionar(ClienteFornecedorDto dto)
    {
        int res = _appCliFor.Adicionar(dto);

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        return Json(res, settings);
    }
```

O objeto `dto` está vindo com as propriedades `null`

Comment: Confirma se os nomes das propriedades do objeto ClienteFornecedor estão iguais aos do ClienteFornecedorDto.

Comment: Sim são iguais, a unica diferença é o Id que é `int`, mas acredito que não interfere. E é uma classe que tem herança e um método. não sei se interfere.

Comment: Tenta assim: var dto = $.toJSON(ClienteFornecedor);

Comment: Esse método é exclusivo de uma bilbioteca que eu não tenho.. o stringify está convertendo.. eu testei

Comment: public JsonResult Adicionar([FromBody]ClienteFornecedorDto dto) e ver se funciona!

Comment: Não.. agora o objeto vem completamente `null`

Comment: além do from body, adicione o [HttpPost] antes da declaração da controller e poste a sua DTO para vermos se ela bate com o objeto que está postando... E quando você diz que tudo vem null, o que vinha preenchido antes?

Comment: Adiciona também o Json que está sendo postado, você consegue capturar pelo browser mesmo.

Comment: Tudo isso que vocês me falaram (HttpPost e FromBody) deram certo, porém precisei ajustar o ajax. `data: JSON.stringify(ClienteFornecedor);` Deu certo. Muito Obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, poderia tentar fazer a action da seguinte forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Adicionar([FromBody] ClienteFornecedorDto dto)
```